# Enhancing 8 bit images to 16 bit

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My objective is to enhance 8 bit images to 16 bit ones. In other words, I want to increase the dynamic range of an 8 bit image. And to do that, I can sequentially take multiple images of 8 bit with fixed scene and fixed camera. To simplify the issue, let's assume they are grayscale images

Intuitively, I think I can achieve the goal by

1. Multiplying two 8 bit images

   `resimage = double(img1) .* double(img2)`
2. Averaging specified number of 8 bit images

   `resImage = mean(images,3)`

assuming `images(:,:,i)` contains `i`th 8 bit image.

After that, I can make the resulting image to 16 bit one.

```
resImage = uint16(resImage)
```

But before testing these methods, I wonder there is another way to do this - except for buying 16 bit camera, or literature for this subject might be better.

UPDATE: As comments below display, I got great information on drawbacks of simple averaging above and on image stacks for the enhancement.  So it may be a good topic to study after all. Thank all for your great comments.

Comment: Are you doing this to increase the resolution of the images? I might be wrong but multiplying two 8 bit images is not going to increase the details in the image. The float values might be 16 bit but quality of the image would not be increased.

Comment: @kkuilla Yes, I want to increase accuracy of each pixels of the image. I think you are right on multiplying two images but how much better than single image or worse than specified number of images are unknown to me.

Comment: Why do you think multiplying two images would increase the accuracy? It might make sense mathematically but nothing is stronger than its weakest link in the end.

Comment: @kkuilla Hmm.. Could you elaborate? I can't see why the multiplied image sequentially taken with fixed camera and scene is not better than single 8 bit image.

Comment: I agree with kkuilla and Jigg .  Taking an collection of images at a lower resolution won't guarantee making your image a higher resolution.  Also, simply mulitplying a stream of images will eventually overflow the data type and will make your image white.  As you keep multiplying numbers, you will eventually go beyond 255, which is the maximum possible unsigned number that data type can hold.  Averaging will not work either.  You are essentially doing a running average, which is basically a low-pass filter.  You would thus be **blurring** your image, removing some high-pass/edge components.

Comment: Adding on to my original post, you could solve the overflow issue with multiplying by taking [Geometric Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) but this will still eventually perform some kind of low-pass filtering and you will still get a blurred result.

Comment: Wait Wait...I don't want to increase spatial resolution of the image. I want to increase depth of each pixel. And by sampling more, I thought I could achieve more depth. You guys are saying this is not true?

Comment: @Tae-SungShin: Unfortunately not true.  If it truly was, then a lot of image processing algorithms would behave differently (and I would be out of a job!)  Also, I wasn't talking about spatial resolution either.  I was talking about the maximum range of possible values your pixel can take (i.e. depth).  Averaging will decrease the dynamic range of your pixels and multiplying will overflow all your data. "Sampling more" just means that you are estimating the values in between the finite locations of your pixels better. You would be interpolating between known values, not increasing depth.

Comment: @rayryeng As you can see in my code, I can easily overcome those overflow issues in Matlab. I don't think that's an issue here. But still I don't see why more sampling does not create more depth. Maybe I am too mathematical.

Comment: If you looked at my very first post, even if you could overcome those issues, you are still essentially doing a running average and thus you would be **losing** information instead of gaining.  As what Jigg said, averaging multiple images is good for reducing white / Gaussian noise and is a low-pass filter.  Edge information and finer details would be lost, and you would thus be restricting the dynamic range of your intensity / colour values.  FWIW, this is a cool question to ask, but it sucks that we couldn't give you the answer you wanted.

Comment: @rayryeng OK. This might be good info. I will read your comment more carefully. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you considered looking at [Superresolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution)?  This **does not** increase the depth per pixel, but it essentially sharpens the image and gives more detail.  Most techniques however are done on the hardware side so I'm not sure if this is applicable to you.

Comment: The OP is asking to increase the Dynamic Range of the image, which has been is being confused in some responses with with spatial resolution i.e. pixel count.  The question is whether a set of 8 bit images (presumably of the same object without movement) can be combined into a 16 bit image with a higher dynamic range, by integrating data from individual 8 bit images.  I understand that this IS possible, and is a common practice in astronomical imaging where so called "image stacks" are averaged together.  Take a look at http://keithwiley.com/astroPhotography/imageStacking.shtml for explanation

Comment: @rayryeng I will look into superresolution. Thanks. It was great tips.

Comment: @jcollomosse:  I guess I was confused.  I didn't realize that the OP wanted to increase dynamic range.  In that case, then HDR will work as well by taking multiple exposures of the scene.  I thought the OP wanted to take images of the same environment with the same parameters (exposure, lighting, etc.).  In that case, I shouldn't have assumed.... I certainly made an @$$ of myself!

Comment: @jcollomosse That's great explanation and thanks for the info on image stacks. I think it can be great start point for my study. Would you mind creating an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: @jcollomosse: Agreed.  I will upvote.  I would also recommend the OP slightly modify the question as it is misleading.  I didn't realize the goal was to increase dynamic range.

Comment: @rayryeng sorry for the confusion I caused. I thought depth of pixel implies dynamic range of image but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin: Not a problem!  I apologize for being confrontational.  I should have clarified what you were asking instead of jumping on the bandwagon with the others and trying to disprove something that you never originally asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question appears to relate to increasing the Dynamic Range of an image by integrating information from multiple 8 bit exposures into a 16 bit image.  This is related to the practice of capturing and combining "image stacks" in astronomical imaging among other fields.  An explanation of this practice and how it can both reduce image noise, and enhance dynamic range is available here:

http://keithwiley.com/astroPhotography/imageStacking.shtml

The idea is that successive captures of the same scene are subject to image noise, and this noise leads to stochastic variation of the pixel values captured.  In the simplest case these variations can be leveraged by summing and dividing i.e. mean averaging the stack to improve its dynamic range but the practicality would depend very much on the noise characteristics of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

You want to sum many images together, assuming there is no jitter and the camera is steady.  Accumulate a large sum and then divide by some amount.

Note that to get a reasonable 16-bit image from an 8 bit source, you'd need to take hundreds of images to get any kind of reasonable result.  Note that jitter will distort edge information and there is some inherent noise level of the camera that might mean you are essentially 'grinding metal'.  In a practical sense, you might get 2 or 3 more bits of data from image summing, but not 8 more.  To get 3 bits more would require at least 64 images (6 bits) to sum.  Then divide by 8 (3 bits), as the lower bits are garbage.

Rule of thumb is to get a new bit of data, you need the squared(bits) of images, so 3 bits (8) means 64 images, 4 bits would be 256 images, etc.

Here's a link that talks about sampling:

http://electronicdesign.com/analog/understand-tradeoffs-increasing-resolution-averaging

"In fact, it can be shown that the improvement is proportional to the square root of the number of samples in the average."

Note that SNR is a log scale so equating it to bits is reasonable.

Comment: That's excellent. Can you give reference I can follow on your answer?

Comment: It's not really a rule of thumb.  It's a SNR thing.  I'll try to find a reference.