# How to average multiple images using Octave and matrix manipulation to reduce noise?

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, octave

UPDATE
Here is my code that is meant to add up the two matrices and using element by element addition and then divide by two.

```
function [ finish ] = stackAndMeanImage (initFrame, finalFrame)

cd 'C:\Users\Disc-1119\Desktop\Internships\Tracking\Octave\highway\highway (6-13-2014 11-13-41 AM)';

pkg load image; 

i = initFrame;
f = finalFrame;

astr = num2str(i);

tmp = imread(astr, 'jpg');

d = f - i

for a = 1:d

        a

        astr = num2str(i + 1);

        read_tmp = imread(astr, 'jpg');

        read_tmp = rgb2gray(read_tmp);

        tmp = tmp  :+ read_tmp; 

        tmp = tmp / 2; 


end 

imwrite(tmp, 'meanimage.JPG');

finish = 'done';
end
```

Here are two example input images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlcyF.jpg

And here is one output image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByBVy.jpg

I am really confused as to what is happening. I have not implemented what the other answers have said yet though.

OLD

I am working on an image processing project where I am now manually choosing images that are 'empty' or only have the background, so that my algorithm can compute the differences and then do some more analysis, I have a simple piece of code that computes the mean of the two images, which I have converted to grayscale matrices, but this only works for two images, because when I find the mean of two, then take this mean and find the mean of this versus the next image, and do this repeatedly, I end up with a washed out white image that is absolutely useless. You can't even see anything.

I found that there is a function in Matlab called imFuse that is able to average images. I was wondering if anyone knew the process that imFuse uses to combine images, I am happy to implement this into Octave, or if anyone knew of or has already written a piece of code that achieves something similiar to this. Again, I am not asking for anyone to write code for me, just wondering what the process for this is and if there are already pre-existing functions out there, which I have not found after my research.

Thanks,

AeroVTP

Comment: May just be a scaling issue (doubles vs. uint8 etc and the scaling that Octave/MATLAB expects).  However if you want to take the mean of multiple images you shouldn't be doing it sequentially.  Make an image stack (x by y by z, where z is the number of images), and just take the mean along the z direction.

Comment: I am going to try that out now, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can also do it sequentially if you wish.  For a 1D signal of say 5 elements, let's say the mean of this signal was 32.  This means that you are effectively replacing each element in the signal with 32.  If you want to compute the **new mean** to include a 6th element, you can do: `(5*32 + x) / 6`. `x` is the new number you want in.  You can do the same thing with images.   My guess is that you are not properly averaging the image and that's why it's washed out.  As you get a new image, simply multiply the mean image by the sequence number, add the image & divide by the sequence number + 1.

Comment: FWIW, averaging images is done to increase SNR, specifically in obtaining high-resolution imagery from space.  Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658194/enhancing-8-bit-images-to-16-bit .  You're definitely on the right path if you want to decrease noise and increase SNR.

Comment: Yup. You're not averaging them properly. Either do nkjt's approach and stack them as a 3D matrix and find the mean temporally or do my approach in a sequential fashion.  The reason why it gets washed out is because you're not dividing by the proper number.  2 is too small, and your average image will keep increasing in value to the point where it overflows.

Comment: 2 is the intuitive averaging number, what is the proper number to average it by?

Comment: You average it by as many images that you have in your stack.  Take a look at what I said above with that example signal of 5 elements.  As you keep reading images in, you need to take your previous image, multiply that by your previous sequence number, add the image, then divide by the current sequence number.  For example: 4th image read in -> `newMeanImage = (3*previousMeanImage + currentImage) / 4;` A special case is when we have two images, which works out to what we expect: `newMeanImage = (1*previousMeanImage + currentImage) / 2;` As you keep reading images in, the number changes.

Comment: Actually 2 is the right divisor in this case. In the beginning we have tmp = (p0+p1)/2, then tmp = ((p0+p1)/2+p2)/2, then tmp = (((p0+p1)/2+p2)/2+p3)/2, etc. It turns out that after several iterations we have, e.g. p100/2 + p99/4 + p98/8 + p97/16 +... which actually is scaled correctly. (Single pole lowpass, one-tap IIR filter, whatever.) This can be seen by understanding that tmp is always correctly scaled after each iteration, and it is averaged with the newest image - resulting a correctly scaled image.

Comment: @AeroVTP Concerning your examples, it looks like you forgot to convert to gray-scale tmp before entering the loop, so seemingly you are averaging a gray-scale image with a color image if I understood your code correctly

Comment: @DrV - Doesn't this mean that the information of the first frame would be lost after the 8th iteration for an 8-bit gray-scale image, or in other words, that only the last 8 frames would contribute information to the average with those weights? Also a low-pass filter could explain the almost white washed image at the end of the process. I like your suggestion of the median filter much better since it could act as an all-pass filter under ideal circumstances.

Comment: @Dissident penguin: Uhhh, yes and no... If we talk about 8-bit values, the question boils down to rounding. Rounding up gives different results from rounding down, but we may also dither the rounding (round randomly up or down), in which case we talk about probabilities of an old sample changing the new sample. But you are spot on to a problem in low-bit-depth signal processing. In this case a bigger problem with the single-pole low pass comes from the non-linear nature of the signal (eight-bit images are gamma-corrected). Nice to hear you like my median suggestion (would you like it by +1?).

Comment: @DrV: If each iteration was stored in a floating point matrix and later converted to 8-bit gray-scale, it could be decided whether to round up, down or dither, but wouldn't implementing this filter in the above code lead to artifacts, on top of the gamma problem, since each iteration is stored in an 8-bit integer matrix?

Comment: @Dissident penguin: Random dither transforms into probabilities later on in the chain, so it can be used with integer arithmetics. Implementing a good random rounding is not that simple, and it is probably faster to calculate in floating point and use the usual rounding. (The random dither idea is more useful in small embedded systems or even logic circuits where it can be implemented easily and FP calculations are fast.) Anyway, this "washed out" problem is not a rounding problem. Also, this is not a gamma problem, even though gamma should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

You should not end up with a washed-out image. Instead, you should end up with an image, which is technically speaking temporally low-pass filtered. What this means is that half of the information content is form the last image, one quarter from the second last image, one eight from the third last image, etc.

Actually, the effect in a moving image is similar to a display with slow response time.

If you are ending up with a white image, you are doing something wrong. nkjt's guess of type challenges is a good one. Another possibility is that you have forgotten to divide by two after summing the two images.

One more thing... If you are doing linear operations (such as averaging) on images, your image intensity scale should be linear. If you just use the RGB values or some grayscale values simply calculated from them, you may get bitten by the nonlinearity of the image. This property is called the gamma correction. (Admittedly, most image processing programs just ignore the problem, as it is not always a big challenge.)

As your project calculates differences of images, you should take this into account. I suggest using linearised floating point values. Unfortunately, the linearisation depends on the source of your image data.

On the other hand, averaging often the most efficient way of reducing noise. So, there you are in the right track assuming the images are similar enough.

---

However, after having a look at your images, it seems that you may actually want to do something else than to average the image. If I understand your intention correctly, you would like to get rid of the cars in your road cam to give you just the carless background which you could then subtract from the image to get the cars.

If that is what you want to do, you should consider using a median filter instead of averaging. What this means is that you take for example 11 consecutive frames. Then for each pixel you have 11 different values. Now you order (sort) these values and take the middle (6th) one as the background pixel value.

If your road is empty most of the time (at least 6 frames of 11), then the 6th sample will represent the road regardless of the colour of the cars passing your camera.

If you have an empty road, the result from the median filtering is close to averaging. (Averaging is better with Gaussian white noise, but the difference is not very big.) But your averaging will be affected by white or black cars, whereas median filtering is not.

The problem with median filtering is that it is computationally intensive. I am very sorry I speak very broken and ancient Octave, so I cannot give you any useful code. In MatLab or PyLab you would stack, say, 11 images to a  M x N x 11 array, and then use a single median command along the depth axis. (When I say intensive, I do not mean it couldn't be done in real time with your data. It can, but it is much more complicated than averaging.)

---

If you have really a lot of traffic, the road is visible behind the cars less than half of the time. Then the median trick will fail. You will need to take more samples and then find the most typical value, because it is likely to be the road (unless all cars have similar colours). There it will help a lot to use the colour image, as cars look more different from each other in RGB or HSV than in grayscale.

Unfortunately, if you need to resort to this type of processing, the path is slightly slippery and rocky. Average is very easy and fast, median is easy (but not that fast), but then things tend to get rather complicated.

---

Another BTW came into my mind. If you want to have a rolling average, there is a very simple and effective way to calculate it with an arbitrary length (arbitrary number of frames to average):

```
# N is the number of images to average
# P[i] are the input frames
# S is a sum accumulator (sum of N frames)

# calculate the sum of the first N frames
S <- 0
I <- 0
while I < N
    S <- S + P[I]
    I <- I + 1

# save_img() saves an averaged image
while there are images to process
    save_img(S / N)
    S <- -P[I-N] + S + P[I]
    I <- I + 1
```

Of course, you'll probably want to use for-loops, and += and -= operators, but still the idea is there. For each frame you only need one subtraction, one addition, and one division by a constant (which can be modified into a multiplication or even a bitwise shift in some cases if you are in a hurry).

Comment: I did the divide by two, I know that that is not the problem. I don't think that it is a type problem, since all of the images are the same type, size etc. I will try doing the gamma correction though, thanks!

Comment: Actually, the division may still be your problem. Even though the maths itself is correct (not giving an average, but still reducing noise), you may still have problems with data overflows. If you are working with 8-bit values, then the calculation (150 + 150) / 2 will give you 22 because the sum overflows. If you calculate 150/2 + 150/2 instead, you'll get 150.

Comment: @user3735428 : That's what I've told the OP :).  I made a suggestion as a comment in his question above.  Glad to see someone else agrees too!

Comment: @rayryeng: If I understood your suggestion correctly (which I may not have done), we have slightly different algorithms. Your algorithm gives the average of first two images, first three images, first four images, etc. in an efficient way. My algorithm gives the rolling average of N consecutive images in an efficient way ("boxcar integration", "FIR with only ones", "rolling average"). Both are useful algorithms.

Comment: @DrV: The algorithm collectively gives the overall average as you introduce a new image in.  If you want the rolling average, then what I suggested won't work.  This technique that I showed keeps updating what the average image is, as a new image is coming in.  However, if you want to implement a rolling average, then the division by 2 is the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood your problem but I think what you're trying to do is the following. Basically, read all images into a matrix and then use `mean()`. This is providing that you are able to put them all in memory.

```
function [finish] = stackAndMeanImage (ini_frame, final_frame)
  pkg load image;

  dir_path = 'C:\Users\Disc-1119\Desktop\Internships\Tracking\Octave\highway\highway (6-13-2014 11-13-41 AM)';

  imgs = cell (1, 1, d);

  ## read all images into a cell array
  current_frame = ini_frame;
  for n = 1:(final_frame - ini_frame)
    fname = fullfile (dir_path, sprintf ("%i", current_frame++));
    imgs{n} = rgb2gray (imread (fname, "jpg"));
  endfor

  ## create 3D matrix out of all frames and calculate mean across 3rd dimension
  imgs = cell2mat (imgs);
  avg = mean (imgs, 3);

  ## mean returns double precision so we cast it back to uint8 after
  ## rescaling it to range [0 1]. This assumes that images were all
  ## originally uint8, but since they are jpgs, that's a safe assumption
  avg = im2uint8 (avg ./255);

  imwrite (avg, fullfile (dir_path, "meanimage.jpg"));
  finish = "done";

endfunction
```